# Floating point: round before normalize or vice-versa?

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

I'm writing a floating point adder in C and am using Berkeley SoftFloat and TestFloat order to test it. A few test cases are failing, which has led me to this contradiction:

- Obviously, it's necessary to normalize before rounding, since prior to normalization, we don't know what the least-significant bit of the significand will be.
- But rounding can actually change the number of digits in the significand, if we're rounding up and all the digits of the significand are already 1.

So it seems necessary to normalize again after rounding.

How is this done in practice? Do implementations just have a check for this case and shift the significand right once (and increase the exponent) in order to compensate?

This is one of several edge cases I've encountered, and I find myself having to look at existing implementations to figure out what to do. But how did the people who wrote those implementations know what to do? Is there some canonical reference for how to implement floating point operations? IEEE 754 describes encodings and specifies required operations but doesn't get into how to actually implement the operations (unless there's some implementation guide that I'm missing).

Comment: Most description of algorithms for rounding when preparing the final result of an operation normalize (or, equivalent, figure out whatever adjustment to the exponent is needed to normalize), then round, then adjust the exponent by one if rounding made that necessary. Of course, any method that gets the same result is acceptable. I do not know what is actually implemented in hardware.

Comment: Publications on hardware design typically appear in *IEEE Symposium on Computer Arithmetic* and *IEEE Transactions on Computers*. A reasonable starting point specifically for IEEE-754 binary floating-point addition would be: Peter-Michael Seidel and Guy Even, "Delay-optimized implementation of IEEE floating-point addition," *IEEE Transactions on Computers*, vol. 53, no. 2, Feb. 2004, pp. 97-113.

Comment: The general rounding/normalization rule is "compute (as if) with infinite precision, then find the nearest representable number" (where "nearest" depends on the rounding mode). In this version of the standard https://doi.org/10.1109%2FIEEESTD.2019.8766229, the relevant (sub-)sections are in Section 4.3, I think. (Your other questions, about implementation details, appear off-topic to me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So it seems necessary to normalize again after rounding.

In the case where rounding "change the number of digits in the significand", the old number was of the form: 1.11111....111<sub>2</sub>*2<sup>expo</sup>.  With an "up" rounding, the new number is of the form 10.00000....000<sub>2</sub>*2<sup>expo</sup>.   A re-normalization then is a trivial: 1.000000....000<sub>2</sub>*2<sup>expo + 1</sup>.

Overflow to infinity is possible if `expo` was at the max value.

---

> How is this done in practice?

In hardware, another row of cells.

In software, just a few more lines of code: a shift, increment and test for max.